# Script to check a web service

Tags: python, python-2.x, status-monitoring, jython

I'm a Python novice. The system I'm using is called IBM [Maximo Asset Management](http://ibm.com/docs/en/mam/7.6.1.2). In Maximo, we can write Python scripts that utilize Maximo's Java API/methods. So the script is technically a [Jython](https://www.jython.org/) script (Python + Java methods).

---

I've written a [scheduled Jython 2.7 script](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/mam/7.6.1.2?topic=product-automating-routine-tasks) for checking an external system's [web service](https://enterprise.arcgis.com/en/server/10.7/publish-services/windows/what-is-a-map-service.htm)  for issues.

The idea is that this script would be run on a nightly schedule -- just after a scheduled integration has completed. I don't have control over the scheduled integration (I can't build this script right into the integration), but at least I can run a separate job to check for possible issues afterwards. And make it email me if it finds any issues.

1. Did the web service produce an error?
2. Are there any records that haven't been synced? (this is the **main reason** for the script)
3. Did the web service time out? (the web service didn't have an error, it just didn't respond)

---

```
from psdi.mbo import MboConstants
from java.util import HashMap
from com.ibm.json.java import JSONObject

#The web service's vendor provides a public sample server that can be used for testing purposes:
url = "https://sampleserver6.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/ServiceRequest/MapServer/1/query?where=SUBMITDT%3CDATE%272018-05-11%27&f=pjson&returnCountOnly=true"

def fetch_row_count(url):
    #Get the JSON text from the web service.
    ctx = HashMap()
    ctx.put("url", url)
    service.invokeScript("LIBHTTPCLIENT", ctx)
    json_text = str(ctx.get("response"))

    #Parse the row count from the JSON text`
    obj = JSONObject.parse(json_text)
    parsed_val = obj.get("count")

    return parsed_val

try:
    result = fetch_row_count(url)
    if result == 0:
        print "All records are synced. No need to do anything."
    #Check 1:
    elif result is None:
        #Email Template "ERROR": "The web service had an error when pinged." 
        #                        "Check for records that have not been synced."
        ctMboSet = mbo.getMboSet("$commtemp", "COMMTEMPLATE", "TEMPLATEID ='ERROR'")
        ctMbo = ctMboSet.getMbo(0)
        ctMbo.sendMessage(mbo, mbo)
    #Check 2:
    elif result > 0:    
        #Email Template "NOSYNC": "There are records that have not been synced."
        ctMboSet = mbo.getMboSet("$commtemp", "COMMTEMPLATE", "TEMPLATEID ='NOSYNC'")
        ctMbo = ctMboSet.getMbo(0)
        ctMbo.sendMessage(mbo, mbo)
except:
    #Check 3
    #Email Template "TIMEOUT": "The web service timed-out when pinged."
    #                          "Check for records that have not been synced.""
    ctMboSet = mbo.getMboSet("$commtemp", "COMMTEMPLATE", "TEMPLATEID ='TIMEOUT'")
    ctMbo = ctMboSet.getMbo(0)
    ctMbo.sendMessage(mbo, mbo)
```

You'll notice that I'm not passing information about errors to the emails that I'm sending (the emails are called "Communication Templates"). I'm not aware of an easy way to pass information, like "Error 500", to the email communication templates. I think I'm stuck with sending generic emails -- the recipient will need to refer to the timestamp of the email and investigate the logs.

---

This is what's called a "[library script](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/maximo-for-utilities/7.6.0?topic=SSLLAM_7.6.0/com.ibm.mbs.doc/autoscript/c_example_reuse.html)" in Maximo:

LIBHTTPCLIENT (referenced in line #11 above)

```
from psdi.iface.router import HTTPHandler
from java.util import HashMap
from java.lang import String

handler = HTTPHandler()
map = HashMap()
map.put("URL", url)
map.put("HTTPMETHOD", "GET")
responseBytes = handler.invoke(map, None)
response = String(responseBytes, "utf-8")
```

---

As a novice, I'm wondering if the script can be improved. Cheers.